# How to get selected JComboBox item count?

Tags: java, swing, count, jcombobox

I am new to java programming and currently doing an e-voting system project for my subject. I used `JComboBox` to let the voters choose who they want. Now, how can I get the count of the selected items when they click submit button and show it to the table on my result page?

Comment: `JComboBox` doesn't support multi-selection, it only supports a single selection, that's the point.  Instead, what you want are a series of `JCheckBox`s if you want to allow multi-selection

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't know that until now. I'll gonna change it right away to a JCheckBox.